# Link não clica em dimensões pequenas

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, link

Eu estou tendo um problema com os links (`<a href=""></a>`) pois em telas normais (desktops) ele é normal como deveria ser, agora quando a resolução é menor tipo mobile ou tablets, o link não fica clicavel, não sei o porque... O site que está com esse problema é o http://vicporai.fatcow.com . Vocês podem testar diminuindo o tamanho do navegador. Meu código está normal (veja o código fonte).

Answer (score 0):

Usando o `Inspecionar Elemento` no seu site notei uma `div` chamada `<div class="col-md-3 sidebar">` que se posiciona à frente de todos os elementos do site, tirei a propriedade `position: relative` dela e os links do site voltaram a funcionar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu retirei o `position` só que continuou a mesma coisa. O que fiz foi colocar `hidden-xs` e `hidden-sm`